# How do I compile/open such a file

Tags: c++, file, opengl, iostream

I don't know how to compile this class, it exits with -1 when I compile it in visual/codeblocks. Do I have to use command line? How do I do that?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if( argc <= 1 )
        return -1;
    Chunk::init();
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    Chunk *obj = read_chunk( f );
    fclose( f );
    delete obj;

    if( argc > 2 )
        return 0;

    OpenGL ogl(&argc,argv);
}

OpenGL ogl(&argc,argv);

}
```

Comment: in run settings there should be a setting for passing command line arguments

Answer (score 1):

As the code suggests, you have to supply a command-line option!

`FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");`

The command-line argument should be some file that will be open by this program. Since you only paste a snippet, I don't know what this program is for.

But say the compiled binary is `a.exe`, then you should run it as:

`a.exe A_FILE_NAME`